# IAM access to all objects in an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

My S3 bucket has random files getting pushed in. One of the automated process assumes a role and tries to list the objects(recursively).

I have been getting the following error while trying to list the object within a directory in the bucket.

```
(AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

This is my current state of the policy

```
{
  "Version": "version_id",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "some_id",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to give List access for all objects within the bucket. Would be glad if someone could help.

Comment: What have you done in your attempt to provide the relevant permission? Please include the policy.

Comment: @jarmod : added

Comment: Worth checking by assuming that role yourself and using awscli to issue `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname`. The combination of action `s3:ListBucket` and resource `arn:aws:s3:::bucketname` should suffice. Perhaps your automated process is issuing additional API calls to S3 that are denied?